# Examples of effective Lefschetz condition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, formal-schemes

When a closed subvariety $Y$ of $X$ satisfy effective Lefschetz condition $Leff(X,Y)$, it implies there is an equivalence if categories between the vector bundles on the formal neighborhood of $Y$ in $X$ and vector bundles on a neighborhood of $Y$. One of functors inducing this equivalence is clear, it is the restriction functor which is exact. Is there any explicit description of the other functor? Is it exact?

A theorem Hartshorne implies that when $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective varieties and $Y$ is a complete intersection with $\text{dim}(Y)\geq 2$, this property holds. I wonder whether there are any interesting examples of pairs that $X$ is a surface and $Y$ is a curve, I'm more interested in having an interesting $X$. (in char $p$ preferably)

Comment: If $X$ is smooth, $\operatorname{Leff}(X,Y) $ implies that the embedding induces an isomorphism $\pi _1(Y)\rightarrow \pi _1(X)$. If $X$ is a surface and $Y$ a curve, this is rather unlikely.

Comment: @abx There are some examples where this isomorphism holds, like ruled surfaces, or $\mathbb P^1$ on rational surfaces. Could the effective Lefschetz be true for those?

Comment: I think there will rarely be an explicit description of the inverse, except  when you have an explicit description of the category of vector bundles on a formal neighborhood. However, since it is an equivalence of categories, it is necessarily exact.

Comment: @Will Sawin: In the case of a ruled, non-rational surface, in order to have an isomorphism on $\pi _1$ $Y$ should be a section of the ruling, hence have negative square; this implies that even $\operatorname{Lef}(X,Y) $ doesn't hold (e.g. $\hat{X}$ has non-constant formal functions). It might be that $\operatorname{Leff} $ holds for some rational curves in a rational surface (with positive square).

Comment: @abx I think sections can have both positive and negative squares - look at the projectivization of $\mathcal O + O(n)$, which has two disjoint sections with squares $n$ and $-n$ respectively.

Comment: @Will Sawin: you are right, sorry. I still suspect that these do not satisfy Lefschetz effective, but I'd have to check.

Comment: @Will Sawin: But equivalence of categories does not necessarily imply exactness. Unless it is between abelian categories. A simple counter-example: equivalence of reflexive sheaves on a variety and complement of a codimension 2 subvariety induced by pull-back and pushforward. Pushforward is not exact.

Comment: Good point. However, a sequence of vector bundles is exact on some open neighborhood of $Y$ as long as it is exact on a formal neighborhood of $Y$, or even on $Y$, because exactness can be expressed as the vanishing of some coherent sheaf and thus is an open condition. So as long as you define exact sequences of vector bundles on a neighborhood of $Y$ to be those that are exact on at least one neighborhood, exactness seems clear.